# Using Eclipse JDT - Must this be from a plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am building out some code using Eclipse's JDT tools - I'm using JDT Core component. However, It seems that I can only build out code using the JDT Core component within a plugin. I was hoping to maybe access some of the classes from the JDT Core component from a regular java project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the JDT components/plug-ins depends on the Eclipse framework and therefore - by extension - will any code you write depend on the Eclipse framework and runtime. Thus, your code must be in the form of a plug-in.

Converting a regular Java project into a Eclipse plug-in is rather simple. You just need `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (or an extension of the one you have) and possibly `plugin.xml`.

But... why do you want a regular Java project in the first place rather than a plug-in? What differences do you expect - apart from the mentioned files?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to be able to invoke some sort of functionality in the plugin without having to define a command. But in light of this, it may be better setting the plugin up as a jar file of libraries instead without any commands. Is it possible to have a plugin as a jar file that doesn't rely on 'commands' defined in the manifest? Thanks for the help

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to invoke the JDT functionality from a batch file or from ANT? If you want to use the functionality from within the Eclipse IDE, then you need a command, a dialog, a wizard or something similar...

Comment: Yeah I was looking to invoke the JDT functionality from within a Java Class file, but I figured that it's not possible as the handlers require events that are inextricably linked to commands. Notwithstanding, i'll make do with what's available. Thanks for the help as always nonty! Regards